# Get-ADuser : A referral was returned from the server

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm getting the following error when I run my script:

```
Get-ADUser : A referral was returned from the server At line:25 char:70
+ ... -Identity $G.name -Recursive | Get-ADUser  -Server $dom -Properties *
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (CN=User...,DC=org:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADReferral    Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:****,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

This is my script:

```
$Domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains.ForEach{(Get-ADDomain $_).PDCEmulator}

$Users = @()
$Groups = @()
$list = Get-Content C:\temp\ADGroups.txt
ForEach ($dom in $Domains) {
    Foreach ($o in $list) {
        $ObjectClass = (Get-ADObject -server $dom -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $o}).ObjectClass
        If ($ObjectClass -eq "User") {
            $U =  Get-ADUser -Properties * -Identity $o -Server $dom
            $User = "" | Select FullUserName, LoginID, Description
            $User.FullUserName = $U.DisplayName
            $User.LoginID = $U.SamAccountName
            $User.Description = $U.description
            $Users += $User
        } Else {
            If ($ObjectClass -eq "Group") {
                $G = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Identity $o -Server $dom
                $GM = Get-ADGroupMember -Server $dom -Identity $G.name -Recursive | Get-ADUser  -Server $dom -Properties *
                Foreach ($gmember in $GM) {
                    $Group = "" | Select GroupName, GroupDescription, GroupMemberName, GroupMemberLoginID, GroupMemberDesc
                    $Group.GroupName = $G.Name
                    $Group.GroupDescription = $G.Description
                    $Group.GroupMemberName = $gmember.Name
                    $Group.GroupMemberLoginID = $gmember.SamAccountName
                    $Group.GroupMemberDesc = $gmember.Description
                    $Groups += $Group
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$Users | Export-Csv C:\temp\Users.csv -NoTypeInformation
$Groups | Export-Csv C:\temp\Groups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The purpose of my script is to pull users that belong in a group and export to a .csv file. It works for the most part, but it gives me an error for certain users. I think it could be because those users in the group belong in a different domain.

Comment: I would recommend an `Elseif` instead of using `Else { If`. Makes it format a little better. You could throw this in a `Try Catch` block to catch the error and see the messages a little easier. You could also exclude the erroneous accounts and dump them into a new CSV for further investigation.

Answer (score 2):

See the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064884/get-adgroupmember-get-aduser-fails-for-users-in-different-domain). Answers there indicate you can retrieve the referral location in the exception and retry the Get-ADUser against the other server.

You might reconsider how you search for all these groups and users. Users are replicated throughout the forest. Global and Universal groups are too. So you *could* search the Global Catalog instead of iterating through one DC in every domain. [`Get-DomainController -GlobalCatalog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/active-directory/get-domaincontroller?view=exchange-ps) and run your Get-AD* commands against that server's global catalog port, i.e. `Get-ADUser -server $GCServerName:3268`

However, bear in mind that the GC doesn't contain complete user and group properties, and the properties it *does* return are subject to replication delays.

Whether this is helpful depends on your domain architecture. In my own workplace, querying remote domain controllers is very expensive. Our site domain controller is a global catalog, though, so searching it for forest information is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can simply drop the `-Server` from `Get-ADUser`. Since `Get-ADGroupMember` returns a `ADPrincipal[]` type, every user contains a fully qualified `DistinguishedName`, which implies the domain ("server") that the results come from.

Yes, you are right in thinking that essentially (pesudocode):

```
"contoso.com\user" | Get-ADUser -Server "DC01.theOtherContoso.com"
```

Will not work. And when piping from `Get-ADGroupMember`, you get the error:

> Get-ADUser : A referral was returned from the server

If you run the same query, but omitting the `-Server` portion from the `Get-ADUser` portion, it will use the distinguished name to figure out where to pull the information:

```
$GM = Get-ADGroupMember -Server $dom -Identity $G.name -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties *
```

It should return you the user objects that you need.

Comment: I'm getting the following error : `Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'groupname' under: 'DC=mmroot,DC=org'.
At line:22 char:8
+  $GM = Get-ADGroupMember -Server $dom -Identity $G.name -Recursive |`