# How to export all AD Group Members using PowerShell?

Tags: active-directory, group-membership

I am trying to export all members from all of our AD Groups. I tried exporting all members using "Get-ADGroup"s "member" properties. We have around ~400k groups in our forest consisting of multiple domains. When I exported the members of all groups, it turns out the output is missing members from ~60k groups.

I checked few of the groups one by one using Get-ADGroup, and they don't show any members at all as the output file. However, I know for a fact that these groups have members via Azure AD. Also, when I looked up these users' "memberOf" property using Get-ADUser, I didn't see those groups.

So essentially, PowerShell Get-ADUser's memberOf and Get-ADGroup's member attributes are not showing some membership relationships even though the relationships exist.

Why is it happening? and What's the best way to export all members from all groups?

Btw, I tried using Get-ADGroupMember for each group separately, but it does not work and requires the script to be run from a DC, which is not possible.

Comment: I'm not following everything you're saying. `Get-ADGroupMember` does not need to be run from a DC - it just needs to be run from a computer joined to the domain, or any computer with network access to the domain with the `-Server` parameter.

Comment: Are the missing memberships from groups that are the primary groups of users (like `Domain Users`)? Primary groups don't show up in `memberOf` of the user or the `member` attribute of the group.

Comment: Hi @GabrielLuci,

Sorry for the confusion. 
_**Get-ADGroupMember -identity "GROUP_GUID" -server COMPANY.COM:3268**_ returns this error: _get-adgroupmember : The operation is not supported on Global Catalog port._

When ran directly against a domain like this _**Get-ADGroupMember -identity "GROUP_GUID" -server DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM**_, it returns 0 for the actual domain the group hosted in and returns this error from other domain: _get-adgroupmember : A referral was returned from the server_

Comment: Thanks for the info on primary groups; however, that's not the case. I am missing members from 60k groups, and they are coming from different categories and different scopes.

Comment: A referral means that you're not connecting to the domain that the group is on. The server does tell you which server you should be connecting to, which you can get if you look at the details of the exception by using a try/catch block like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48323777/1202807)